# Passing Json array to custom directive Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I am using angular 5. I want to pass a json array to the custom directive.

My code:

product.ts

```
products=[{"laptop":"dell", id:1}, {"laptop":"lenovo", id:2}];
```

product.html

```
<div product-data="{{data}}" *ngFor="let data of products"></div>
```

product-data.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[product-data]'
})
export class ProductDetailsDirective {
    @Input('template-thumbnail') productSelected:any;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.productSelected)
    }
}
```

on logging the productSelected  i am getting a string **[object Object]** instead of an array

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your array is `products` but you're passing to your directive `data`...which is a product (Object) of your array.

Comment: Interpolated data is always stringified. And i don't see any inputs with `product-data` name in your directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<div [product-data]="data" *ngFor="let data of products"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `@Input('template-thumbnail') productSelected:any[];`(this will print it as a string) as
`@Input('template-thumbnail') productSelected:any[];` which declares it as array type.

Or

You can use JSON.parse to parse the string to array.

`JSON.parse(this.productSelected)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this pipe function

```
<div product-data="{{data | json}}" *ngFor="let data of products"></div>
```

I did not test this. So if in your directive you get data as string just use JSON.parse to convert it back to object.

Another solution is to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse functions.
Here is how I should use them in your case.

product.html

```
 <div product-data="convertData(data)" *ngFor="let data of products"></div>
```

product.ts

```
products=[{"laptop":"dell", id:1}, {"laptop":"lenovo", id:2}];

convertData(data){ 
  return JSON.stringify(data)
}
```

product-data.ts

Inside your directive class just use parse function to convert it back to JSON Object JSON.parse()